# Z3 Fixedpoints: What is the meaning of formula false in model?

Tags: z3

I'm trying to check a simple Timed Automata for reachability using Z3's fixed-point engine.

The TA I'm modeling is:

-->(x = 0 & 0 <= c <= 5) --[c > 2]-->(x = 1)

I want to verify that the state x = 1 & c = 3 is reachable. To do that I input the following into Z3:

```
(declare-rel T (Int Real Int Real))
(declare-rel REACH (Int Real))
(declare-var x Int) 
(declare-var c Real)
(declare-var nx Int)
(declare-var nc Real)
(declare-var delay Real)
(rule (! (=> (and (= x 0) (> c 2.0)) (T x c 1 c)) :named stepint))
(rule (! (=> (and (REACH x c) (T x c nx nc)) (REACH nx nc)) :named tstep))
(rule (! (=> (and (= c 0.0) (= x 0)) (REACH x c)) :named initialstates))
(rule (! (let ((a!1 (and (>= delay 0.0) (= nc (+ c delay)) (or (not (= x 0)) (< nc 5.0)))))
(=> a!1 (T x c x nc))) :named TICK))

(query (and (REACH x c) (= x 1) (= c 3.0))
 :print-certificate true)
```

When I run the above in Z3 on rise4fun I get back:

```
formula false in model: (= REACH_1_0 3.0)
formula false in model: (= REACH_0_0 1)
formula false in model: (= query!0_0_n 1)
formula false in model: (= query!0_1_n 3.0)
sat
(REACH 1 3.0)
```

Which indicates that x= 1 & c = 3 is reachable. What does "formula false in model mean"? Is this simply informational or is Z3 warning me about potentially poorly formed input?

Answer (score 0):

The bugs appear fixed in the "opt" branch. I have not ported the fixes to the unstable branch yet. It will happen, but if impatient, use the "opt" branch.
Sorry.